# WiFi not working after latest update

Tags: 13.04, wireless

I recently updated Ubuntu 13.04 and since then the WiFi does not work. It does not even show up in the drop down menu by the clock. Drivers are installed still and ndiswrapper is there, here is some info hope it helps.

*iwconfig*

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.
```

*ifconfig*

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:e0:b8:e4:a7:e9  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5350 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5350 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:442173 (442.1 KB)  TX bytes:442173 (442.1 KB)

usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:50:56:54:61:61  
          inet addr:192.168.42.234  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::50:56ff:fe54:6161/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:79704 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55609 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:112940929 (112.9 MB)  TX bytes:7081971 (7.0 MB)
```

And I'm also getting this

```
    sudo modprobe ndiswrapper
    ERROR: could not insert 'ndiswrapper': Exec format error
```

Additional info

```
ndiswrapper -l
mrv8335 : driver installed
netmw14x : driver installed
    device (11AB:2A08) present
```

Comment: Internal or external (usb adapter or what) wireless interface? What's the card/adapter name?
Also, can you please provide us this output? `ndiswrapper -l`

Comment: After an upgrade: If you can try to connect with cable (ethernet) to the internet and download all available updates. The WIFI  might work again.

Comment: @ PeppeDAlterio: Marvel topdog wireless card (internal) and I've added the additional info, thanks. @ Jonathan: It's been connected via cable for about a week now everything is up to date as far as I can tell.

Comment: I just re-ran the updater there were some things that updated but it did not help.

Comment: No Ideas anyone?